# Edit a single batch file that contains a single IP in multiple lines with a new batch file

Tags: batch-file, ip-address, command-line-arguments

I have a batch file in C:\Temp\Backup\ that is named backup.bat. In backup.bat the text below exist. I would like to create a batch file that changes the 172.16.17.4 to 192.168.1.104 in backup.bat for every line where 172.16.17.4 is at.

The purpose is to have external users edit an IP address once and to avoid user error of editing multiple lines in the backup.bat file.

Can you help?

```
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cd /d C:\Temp\Backup\172.16.17.4\BOS
ren "C:\Temp\Backup\172.16.17.4\BOS\DATA.DB" "DATA-%stamp%.DB" >nul
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cd /d C:\Temp\Backup\172.16.17.4\FCC
ren "C:\Temp\Backup\172.16.17.4\FCC\DATA.DB" "DATA-%stamp%.DB" >nul
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cd /d C:\Temp\Backup
start "" putty.exe -load -ssh user@172.16.17.4 -l user -pw password
timeout /t 20 /nobreak
plink -ssh user@172.16.17.4 -pw password -batch drvctrl 1
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
plink -ssh user@172.16.17.4 -pw password -batch pkill fccloader
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
plink -ssh user@172.16.17.4 -pw password -batch pkill FCC
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
plink -ssh user@172.16.17.4 -pw password -batch pkill BOS
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
start "" pscp -l user -pw password user@172.16.17.4:/usr/local/dir/BOS/DB/DATA.DB C:\Temp\Backup\172.16.17.4\BOS\DATA.DB
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
start "" pscp -l user -pw password user@172.16.17.4:/usr/local/dir/DB/DATA.DB C:\Temp\Backup\172.16.17.4\FCC\DATA.DB
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
plink -ssh user@172.16.17.4 -pw password -batch reboot
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
taskkill /f /im putty.exe
```

Comment: My suggestion: [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034) on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Pass the IP address as an argument to the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to pass the IP in as an argument, like @DavidPostill suggested. Alternatively, you could use a variable at the top of the batch file so you only need to edit one thing:

```
SETLOCAL
SET theIPaddress=172.16.17.4
cd /d C:\Temp\Backup\%theIPaddress%\BOS
ren "C:\Temp\Backup\%theIPaddress%\BOS\DATA.DB" "DATA-%stamp%.DB" >nul
cd /d C:\Temp\Backup\%theIPaddress%\FCC
ren "C:\Temp\Backup\%theIPaddress%\FCC\DATA.DB" "DATA-%stamp%.DB" >nul
cd /d C:\Temp\Backup
plink -ssh user@%theIPaddress% -pw password -batch "drvctrl 1; pkill fccloader; pkill FCC; pkill BOS"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
start "" pscp -l user -pw password user@%theIPaddress%:/usr/local/dir/BOS/DB/DATA.DB C:\Temp\Backup\%theIPaddress%\BOS\DATA.DB
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
start "" pscp -l user -pw password user@%theIPaddress%:/usr/local/dir/DB/DATA.DB C:\Temp\Backup\%theIPaddress%\FCC\DATA.DB
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
plink -ssh user@%theIPaddress% -pw password -batch reboot
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
ENDLOCAL
```

I removed a bunch of the waits that were not needed and I consolidated all the first commands in to one line.